# How can I create a makefile that will create two separate executables?

Tags: compilation, makefile

I'm very new to makefiles and using one that was given to us for a project, and I'm expanding it a little bit.

This makefile currently takes one arg, the name of the executable you want to make. In the following code, the command `make shapes` would create me a an executable called `shapes`.

```
GCC_OPTIONS=-Wall -pedantic -I include
GL_OPTIONS=-lGLEW -lGL -lglut
OPTIONS=$(GCC_OPTIONS) $(GL_OPTIONS)

.cpp:
    g++ $@.cpp Common/InitShader.o $(OPTIONS) -o $@
```

Now what I've done to my project is created a copy of it and changed some of the data to see how it will effect the output of the program. The original was called `shapes.cpp` and the other version is called `shapes2.cpp`.

What I tried was adding the following line under the current g++ line, but to no avail. I tried to hardcode the '2' part of the file name, presumably incorrectly.

```
g++ $@2.cpp Common/InitShader.o $(OPTIONS) -o $@2
```

Could anyone help me come up with a solution? Again, I have 2 separate cpp files I want to compile as two separate executables. I don't have a problem changing the makefile to hardcode the file names, but I'm a bit unsure how to do that.

Edit: Is there a reason this won't work either? It's complaining that it's missing a seperator on line 13, where it compiles the second program.

```
GCC_OPTIONS=-Wall -pedantic -I include
```

GL_OPTIONS=-lGLEW -lGL -lglut
OPTIONS=$(GCC_OPTIONS) $(GL_OPTIONS)

```
.PHONY: all original modified

all: original modified

original:
    g++ shapes.cpp Common/InitShader.o $(OPTIONS) -o shapes

modified:
    g++ shapes2.cpp Common/InitShader.o $(OPTIONS) -o shapes2
```

Comment: You want to build `shapes` and `shapes2`. What command or commands do you want to do this? I mean, do you want `make shapes` to result in the building of both? Or something else?

Comment: `make shapes` would be ideal, but simply calling `make` and then have it output the two would also be fine.

Comment: Check to be sure that the whitespace in front of line 13 is a TAB, not just four spaces.

Comment: @Beta that was the issue, it was spaces. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above the ".cpp:" line, add this:

```
shapes: shapes2
```

Now the command `make shapes` will result in the building of both (assuming the source files are present and correct).

Comment: Hmm. I tried that, and it did not build a second executable. I shouldn't have my second g++ line I mentioned, right?

Comment: @iaacp: It didn't build "a second executable"? which one *did* it build? And what happens when you `make shapes2`? The second g++ line you mentioned was in a failed experiment; my answer refers to the original makefile.

Comment: the issue was with the tab, as you mentioned previously. This fix worked. Thank you!